# How to generate 64 bit Visual Studio project for LLVM using CMake?

Tags: cmake, llvm-clang

I have downloaded LLVM source repository form http://releases.llvm.org/download.html.

Now when I am running CMAKE in the source directory it is generating 32bit Visual Studio Projects but I want to generate 64 bit visual studio projects. If someone has already tried please help.

I have gone through the document https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html and certainly as mentioned `-Thost=x64` option is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to choose the `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` generator using the option `-G`.