# CMake builds 32-bit library, although my machine runs on 64-bits

Tags: opengl, cmake, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to build the OpenGL library [GLFW3](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) according to [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window). CMake builds a lib in `./src/Debug`, but when I try to link it, VS2017 complains:

> Error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

I'm aware that changing the VS-compiler from x64 to Win32 solves the issue, but I need to build a 64-bit-version.

So is there any way to tell CMake to build a 64-version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate 64 bit Visual Studio project for LLVM using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766836/how-to-generate-64-bit-visual-studio-project-for-llvm-using-cmake)